# opengraph create custom story with link to fb page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have issue with creating custom story like this 'user "do something" on fb page'. I have tried to create "do something" action and create story like ' "do something" on "Link" '. It works well with external links, but don't want to work, when I specify https://www.facebook.com/McDonalds as link. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean with 'external links'? Could you provide us an example code of your call and og meta tags?